# rails join 2 tables HABTM

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using mysql & rails 3.0.9
I have two models: Type and Amenity
each model is associated to the other with has_and_belongs_to_many
and using a join table called amenities_types created as:

```
create_table :amenities_types, :id => false do |t|
    t.column :type_id, :integer
    t.column :amenity_id, :integer
end
```

Now for instance I have the following records:

```
types:
id label
1   a
2   b
3   c

amenities:
id  label
1   d
2   e

amenities_types
type_id amenity_id
1          1
1          2
3          2
```

I would like to list the inner join table:

```
type.id type.label. amenity.id amenity.label
1         a           1           d
1         a           2           e
3         c           2           e
```

I tried Type.find(:all, :joins => :amenities) but only the type columns are shown
the same if I do Amenity.find(:all ,:joins => :types) only the amenities columns are shown.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your Amenity model as so:

```
 class Amenity < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :type, :through => :amenities_types
 end
```

then access like:

```
 Amenity.all.includes(:type)
```

To display:

```
Amenity.all.includes(:type).each { |a|
    puts a.label
    puts a.type.label
    # etc.
  }
```

Comment: does it mean that I want to change the association type from "table join" to "model join"? If so, do I need to declare amenities_types model?

Comment: Hmm... I've never explicitly declared an association type. If you use the sytnax above, ActiveRecord will automatically generate the sql join statements required.

Comment: Also, not sure if you have to have a model defined or not. FWIW, I do in my code, with has_one associations to the two entity tables.